# Typescript - Detect value types based on the object key provided

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Given I have a type like:

```
type Foo = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz: boolean;
}
```

I want to have a type `Buzz` which can detect the value type against a key, i.e

```
const abc: Buzz<Foo> = {
  key: 'foo',
  formatter: (detectMe) => {} //I want TS to infer this to be 'number'
};
```

Given the key 'foo' the argument in formatter should be inferred to be `number`. I tried this:

```
interface ColumnDescription<T> {
  label: string;
  key: keyof T;
  formatter?: (datum: T[keyof T]) => void;
}
```

However this results in the argument being inferred to be `number | string | boolean`.

Tried this as well:

```
interface ColumnDescription<T, K extends keyof T> {
  label: string;
  key: K;
  formatter?: (datum: T[K]) => void;
}
```

This sort of works but I always need the specify the key in the second type argument, instead of it happening automatically. i.e:

```
const abc: Buzz<Foo, 'foo'> = { //I don't want to specify the key
  key: 'foo',
  formatter: (detectMe) => {} //This is inferred correctly
};
```

Comment: `type Buzz<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?: {key: K; formatter: (d: T[K])=>void}}[keyof T]`

Comment: @jcalz why just a comment, seems like a reasonable answer

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I don't know, I didn't have time to write a full answer.  I suppose I thought someone else might answer but I can see if it looks like I'm "squatting" on a question, which wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my comment, I'd suggest

```
type Buzz<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: { key: K; formatter: (d: T[K]) => void }
}[keyof T];
```

which is similar to what you did with `Buzz<T, K extends keyof T>`, but instead of making `Buzz` need `K` to be specified, I used a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` which automatically iterates over keys in `keyof T` and makes a new object with the same keys but whose property values are the types you're looking for.  That means to get the desired `Buzz<T>` we need to [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property values, by indexing into it with `[keyof T]`.  That makes `Buzz<T>` a union of types, where each constituent of the union corresponds to your `Buzz<T, K extends keyof T>` for a particular key `K`

Let's make sure it works:

```
const abc: Buzz<Foo> = {
  key: "foo",
  formatter: detectMe => {} // inferred as number, as desired
};
```

Looks good, and let's inspect the type of `abc` with IntelliSense:

```
const abc: {
    key: "foo";
    formatter: (d: number) => void;
} | {
    key: "bar";
    formatter: (d: string) => void;
} | {
    key: "baz";
    formatter: (d: boolean) => void;
}
```

That looks good too.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAzBAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuTKcgQyoIGdgqBLQgczqyYAvAuQQAbCI0J0AvnXShIUAELFBggDwAVAHzI09ANoBpKNygBrCCDjYoWgLoBaAPwFUl6wWM0ccKqSMwMDUBAAUACYEWiYOAJTIegBucJwRUDLoMoZWNnaO8gDGcITsUIzkhQSq6hrwcHooGFi5BABEuHBtADT0uAFBISxQERAhhcAAstBIeqgyUAD0i2aE2NRUEOmMrERklFTd5bujrJybEVnyy6uskBNQitC25ZXoiwBU6MWlwK9VBiwLS8UA6CDa-CB-UCwVCUEiBBIFGoCVmUBSaVkUAAPoCga1QUwqBD6FhoYM4QioOwuLxUclUhEsbjmviQW0hCSgX4BrDhlTRHAJFJ6ejGbJ0B9FkA)