# Typescript - detecting type based on key when creating a redux reducer that takes key value pair as payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

Newish to Typescript. I and moving a project to TS and I am struggling to define the Typescript for my reducers when creating a slice using redux-toolkit. The scenario is I have filters stored in a state. I have a query string and an object of fields that will be filtered if a value is present. The type of each field depends on the data stored in that field. To set a field filter value I have created a reducer that accepts a key and value pair as the payload. I then use that to set the filter value for that field. After all of my Googling, ChatGPTing and Gemini-ing I am still getting the following error.

```
Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] & string'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[] & string'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
(property) filters: WritableDraft<FilterValues>
```

This is the code for the slice. I have tried multiple types for the payload of setFilter and removeFilter and have left two of the setFilters to show what I have tried.

```
import { PayloadAction, createSelector, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from "redux/store";

export type FilterValues = {
  tags_map: string[];
  reference: string;
  time_executed: string;
  type: string;
}

interface State {
  filterQuery: string;
  filters: FilterValues;
}

const initialState:State = {
  filterQuery: '',
  filters: {
    tags_map: [],
    reference: '',
    time_executed: '',
    type: '',
  },
};

type KeyValuePayload<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { 
    key: K; 
    value: T[K]
  }
}[keyof T];

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'filters',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setFilterQuery: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.filterQuery = payload
    },
    // setFilter : (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ key: keyof FilterValues, value:  FilterValues[keyof FilterValues] }>) => {      
    //   state.filters[payload.key] = payload.value
    // },
    setFilter : (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<KeyValuePayload<FilterValues>>) => {     
      const { key, value } = payload
      state.filters[key] = value
    },
    removeFilter: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<keyof FilterValues>) => {      
      state.filters[payload] = initialState.filters[payload]
    },
    removeAllFilters: (state) => {      
      return { ...state, filters: initialState.filters }
    },
  },
});

export const { 
  setFilterQuery,
  setFilter,
  removeFilter,
  removeAllFilters,
} = slice.actions;

export default slice. Reducer;
```

Sample payload

```
setFilter({key: "reference", value: "foobar"})
setFilter({key: "tags_map", value: ["foo", "bar"]})
```

I am at a loss. I used the approach explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837244/12033293), and trying it in [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wedBXW) it infers the correct types. But it I am still getting errors. I am sure there is a simple answer to this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, I have a hard time figuring out what your Payload actually is supposed to like. Can you maybe give a simple example of that concrete type being passed to that action?

Comment: Opps! @Samulsen, certainly I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does give you the "outer api shape" that's appropriate for calling the `setFilter` action creator for you, but inside your `setFilter` reducer function, that code is just far too generic to ever be correctly typed by TypeScript.

There's a limit where TypeScript can help you, and you're far beyond that limit - your code is just too generic. You'll have to slap a few `any`s in there and call it a day.
`as any` means "I know more than the compiler", and in this case, that's all you can do.

Comment: Thank you @phry. I was confused as calling `setFilter` enforced the type correctly and thought that they type inside `setFilter` would be inferred from the payload type. Still wrapping my head around TS. Appreciate the answer. Should I be taking a different approach to seting the filter values?

Comment: Generally, I'd recommend to avoid setter-style reducers like this, (see the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/)), but for something like a filter it's probably okay.
The problem you are facing here is that the type you get as a payload can have so many different meanings that TS cannot keep track of it anymore correctly. So with code like that, you won't get around ignoring compiler errors.

Comment: Thank you . Really appreciate your help understanding this. Thanks for the info on style also. In this case the user action really is setting a filter, but I have user setter style reducers elsewhere and going to rethink them.

Answer (score 0):

so essentially I see now the problem after you provided the sample Payload. Essentially phry is right, TypeScript can only go so far with its compiler, but I was able to hack around that limitation by using a TypeUnion approach combined with if statements that help the compiler understand what is going on. At least in my TypeScript environment that did the trick:

```
type FilterValues = {
  tags_map: string[];
  reference: string;
  time_executed: string;
  type: string;
};

type State = {
  filterQuery: string;
  filters: FilterValues;
};

type KeyValue =
  | { key: "tags_map"; value: string[] }
  | { key: "reference"; value: string }
  | { key: "time_executed"; value: string }
  | { key: "type"; value: string };


const initialState: State = {
  filterQuery: "",
  filters: {
    tags_map: [],
    reference: "",
    time_executed: "",
    type: "",
  },
};

const setFilter = (payload: KeyValue) => {
    const { key, value } = payload;
    if (typeof value === "string" && !(key === "tags_map")) {
        initialState.filters[key] = value
    }
    if (Array.isArray(value) && key === "tags_map") {
        initialState.filters[key] = value
    }
};

setFilter({ key: "tags_map", value: ["tag1", "tag2"] }); // no error
setFilter({ key: "tags_map", value: "ref1" }); // has error
```

Its a bit verbose, but you get basically what you want :)

Comment: Thank you @samulsen. You are right, putting type guards in does overcome the errors. I think given types are enforced when calling `setFilter` I am ok with `as any` approach as I know I can't send it the wrong payload, and its cleaner code. As I am adopting Typescript I just thought using `any` was the cardinal sin. I really appreciate your help in understanding this one.